# Passing dynamic content into the body of batch notifications using Twillio's Notify API

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api, notify

I'm utilizing Twillio's Notify API to send batch notifications to users. That part is pretty simple in Node.js:

```
async function sendPaymentScheduledMessage(numbers) {
    const bindings = numbers.map(number => {
      return JSON.stringify({ binding_type: 'sms', address: number });
    });

    return await service.notifications.create({
      body: `The payment of your balance is scheduled for this Friday.`,
      toBinding: bindings,
    });
  }
```

Now, I would like to pass user-specific content (first name, amount, account number etc.) into those messages. The API docs mention the possibility of passing a data object, but are unclear (in my opinion) on how to make that happen exactly. I imagine it would be something similar to the extent of:

```
async function sendPaymentScheduledMessage(users) {
    const bindings = users.map(user => {
      return JSON.stringify({ binding_type: 'sms',
                              address: user.number, 
                              data: { 'name': user.name 
                                      'amount': user.amount
                                    }
                            });
      });

    return await service.notifications.create({
      body: `Dear *name*, payment of *amount* is scheduled for this Friday.`,
      toBinding: bindings,
    });
  }
```

But so far I haven't been able to figure out the correct structure. If anyone has made this happen, I'd be grateful to know.

Answer (score 1):

The [`ToBinding`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/notify/api/notification-resource#tobinding-attributes) attributes only contain `binding_type` and `address`.

[`data`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/notify/api/notification-resource#notification-properties) is reserved for custom key-value pairs of the notification's payload. This works for FCM, GCM and APNS but not for SMS.

If you want to customise the body text just use regular JavaScript string interpolation, e.g.:

```js
return await service.notifications.create({
  body: `Dear ${name}, payment of ${amount} is scheduled for this Friday.`,
  toBinding: bindings,
});
```

If you need to customise this for each user then you need to call `service.notifications.create` multiple times.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That's what I've been trying to avoid, calling the method separately for each user. In that scenario I don't see any value in using service.notifications and bindings, as the basic Twillio client.messages.create will suffice. But then I'm stuck with making hundreds of calls at a time.

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here, just to confirm that the Notify API does not support custom body text per message and if you have hundreds of personalised messages to send then you will need to make one request per message. Do be aware, particularly when doing this in JavaScript, that there is a limit of 100 concurrent API requests, so you will likely want to use a queueing mechanism to control that concurrency, and depending on how many messages, you may want a background queue.